# SQL Server : inserting text with escape characters and then reading it in same format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP webpage that gets a string from the user. These strings are usually complex SQL queries or code snippets, so I need to insert them into database with the characters like \n, \r. And then read it in the same format so all another user has to do is copying the code and running it.

Problem is, when inserting to database, they are cut. I am using SQL Server, here is my code for inserting to database:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();

string db= null;
db = connectionstr;
conn.ConnectionString = veritabani;
conn.Open();

db = null;
string detail = this.txtdetail.Text;

command = conn.CreateCommand();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnFilename.Value))
{
    query.Append(" INSERT INTO SUPPORT (title, detail, date) VALUES (?,?,?) ");
    command.CommandText = query.ToString();

    command.Parameters.Add("@title", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtbaslik.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@detail", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = detail;
    command.Parameters.Add("@date", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
else
{
    query.Append(" INSERT INTO SUPPORT (baslik, detail, date, file) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
    command.CommandText = query.ToString();

    command.Parameters.Add("@title", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtbaslik.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@detail", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = detail;
    command.Parameters.Add("@date", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    command.Parameters.Add("@file", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = hdnFilename.Value;
}

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command = null;

conn.Close();
conn = null;
```

Code works fine and inserts into the database, had to translate a few variables to give you guys a better idea, original has no syntax errors.

Comment: What do you mean they are cut? In SSMS you can only see a portion of the text returned in a given column. And if you have new line data and viewing the results in a grid you only see the first row of data. You can change to view as text. Also you can adjust the amount of text displayed in the results in the Query Results under Options in SSMS. Slight side track, you should always specify the length of parameters for things like (n)varchar.

Comment: When you query DB, you see and when you retrieve result does it get cut?

Comment: In the database, the row which has the mentioned query has cut some spaces, there are  Inner Join statements coming together. The whole query is kept as one row. What i need is putting also the newline characters and spaces, escape characters so the format wont break, and anyone else reading the query can read it in same format

Comment: Why are you using the old, deprecated `OBDC` stuff? For SQL Server, I'd always recommend using the SQL native client tools - the `System.Data.SqlClient` classes like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`. Also: not sure what happens if you define a parameter of type `OdbcType.VarChar`, but then you provide **no length** for it... try specifying the actual length that the the column in your database has

Comment: Would modifying the code to not use odbc solve the problem? I also have deleted the NVARCHAR but I still cant manage to insert with escape characters. @marc_s The string is read with new lines but in the database insertion they're gone.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, sql statements had comment lines in them, so if I were to copy paste the query, It would not work. Removing them helped, I will leave the question here for future generations. Thank you for the answers.